# Block IP address dynamically in IIS based on Spammy attacks?

Tags: iis, ip

We've got a script kiddie plugging away at one of our websites, and while they don't seem to be causing any problems, they're flooding the logs and generally being irritating. I'm wondering if there are any modules or config settings that could help restrict.

They basically throw in a few thousand http GET requests to a particular page on our checkout, alternately on port 80 and port 443 (no idea if they're responding to the redirect for the protocol at that point). They never seem to POST anything,

The attacker requests a single page about 5-10 times per second from the same IP address. If I notice and block the IP in IIS manually, a few days later they'll try again from a different IP. The attacks only last a few minutes, tend to be seperated by a few hours, and also tend to be worst at weekends.

Anyway - my request, is there a way of configuring IIS, or a module or something I could install, that will add an IP address to the block list if it throws in too many requests in a short space of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in IIS 6, but we do have [Dynamic IP Restrictions](http://www.iis.net/download/DynamicIPRestrictions) in IIS 7 which is still in beta. Also read [Using Dynamic IP Restrictions](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/548/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions/).

Comment: Ahh Cool, We're beginning to host newer sites on IIS7, but the majority are still on 6. But this sounds like exactly what I'm after.

Comment: If you find the reply useful please mark it as answer. Thank you

Comment: Give it time :) Someone might yet come up with an awesome commercial or third party IIS6 compatible module. Assuming they won't, I'll come back.